# The application crashes when choosing a front camera, how to fix it?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a small camera application on the python kivy for android. It uses the front camera of the phone to take a picture and display the image. But as soon as I started testing the application on the phones, I had problems.

---

There are 3 phones:

1) Xiaomi mi a2 (Android 9.0)

2) Redmi note 4x (Android 6.0)

3) Redmi note 3 pro (Android 8.1)

---

When you select the main camera, the application works on all devices, but if you select the front camera, it works only on mi a2.
Error logs on the phones report that the problem is in the `resolution: (1280,720)`, but whatever resolution I put, the application crashes on these 2 devices anyway. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


import time

filename = ''
screenfour = ''

Builder.load_string("""
#:import MDFillRoundFlatButton kivymd.button.MDFillRoundFlatButton
#:import MDIconButton kivymd.button.MDIconButton
#:import MDFlatButton kivymd.button.MDFlatButton
#:import MDFloatingActionButton kivymd.button.MDFloatingActionButton

<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:
        name: "screen_one"
    ScreenTwo:
        name: "screen_two"
    ScreenThree:
        name: "screen_three"
        id: entry
    ScreenFour:
        name: "screen_four"

<ScreenOne>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    FloatLayout:
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'camera'
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.30}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'


<ScreenTwo>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            color: [1,1,1,1]
            text: "Выбрать фон"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_one'

<ScreenThree>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Widget:
            Camera:
                play: True
                id: cam
                index: 0
                resolution: (1280,720)
                size: (500,500)

        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Сделать фото" 
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.50, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.capture()
                root.manager.current = 'screen_four'

        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_two'

<ScreenFour>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            size: root.width, root.height
            source: ''
            id: imageWid
        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'chevron-double-right'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.10}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'down'
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                root.manager.current = 'screen_three'
""")


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None


class ScreenThree(Screen):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    main_widget = None

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['cam']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        photo = camera.export_to_png("/storage/emulated/0/IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        global filename, screenfour
        filename = "/storage/emulated/0/IMG_{}.png".format(timestr)
        screenfour.update()


class ScreenFour(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenFour, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        global screenfour
        screenfour = self

    def update(self, *args):
        global filename
        imageWidget = self.ids['imageWid']
        imageWidget.source = filename


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Interface(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


sample_app = Interface()
sample_app.run()
```

### buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = mycamapp
# (str) Package name
package.name = mycamapplication
# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.camcamcamapp
# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,numpy,opencv,git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git,android
# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements = 

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.upng

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3.7.3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,CAMERA,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE


# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 28

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 29

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 17c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
p4a.source_dir = /home/max/desktop/python-for-android-master/

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 0

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

### Error log:

```
04-12 21:38:23.364  9168  9202 I python  :  kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 59:
04-12 21:38:23.364  9168  9202 I python  :  ...
04-12 21:38:23.364  9168  9202 I python  :       57:                    id: cam
04-12 21:38:23.364  9168  9202 I python  :       58:                    index: 1
04-12 21:38:23.364  9168  9202 I python  :  >>   59:                    resolution: (640,480)
04-12 21:38:23.365  9168  9202 I python  :       60:                    size: dp(500), dp(500)
04-12 21:38:23.365  9168  9202 I python  :       61:        AnchorLayout:
04-12 21:38:23.365  9168  9202 I python  :  ...
04-12 21:38:23.365  9168  9202 I python  :  JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Fail to connect to camera service
```

Comment: Could you please share your `buildozer.spec`

Comment: Of course, attached to the question

Comment: Have you tried not specifying a resolution? That gets you the default resolution.

Comment: If I don't specify the resolution, then it will be just a white screen.

Comment: Then try `resolution: (-1,-1)`.

Comment: I tried, displays a white screen

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to put the `Camera` inside a `Widget`in your `kv` file. The `Camera` is a `Widget`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `size: (500,500)` with `size: dp(500), dp(500)`

## Snippets - kv file

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import dp kivy.metrics.dp
...

<ScreenThree>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        Widget:
            Camera:
                play: True
                id: cam
                index: 0
                resolution: (1280,720)
                size: dp(500), dp(500)
```

### [Kivy Metrics » Dimensions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html#dimensions)

> ```
> dp
> ```
>
> Density-independent Pixels - An abstract unit that is based on the
>   physical density of the screen. With a [density](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html#kivy.metrics.MetricsBase.density) of 1, 1dp is equal
>   to 1px. When running on a higher density screen, the number of pixels
>   used to draw 1dp is scaled up a factor appropriate to the screen’s
>   dpi, and the inverse for a lower dpi. The ratio of dp-to-pixels will
>   change with the screen density, but not necessarily in direct
>   proportion. Using the dp unit is a simple solution to making the view
>   dimensions in your layout resize properly for different screen
>   densities. In others words, it provides consistency for the real-world
>   size of your UI across different devices.

Comment: Comment off `index: 1`

Comment: index: 1 is the front camera, index: 0 is the main camera. Now the main camera also does not work, after changing the code.

Comment: `index` defaults to -1 to allow auto selection.

Comment: Did as you said, the application still crashes, are there any other ways?